# Given $A_1 = \{\emptyset\}$ and $A_{n+1} = A_n \cup (A_n \times A_n)$ define $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_n$, what is $A\times A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given $A_1 = \{\emptyset\}$ and $A_{n+1} = A_n \cup (A_n \times A_n)$ define $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_n$, what is $A\times A$?

I'm kind of lost on this one, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is that what you wanted to write?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!

Comment: In that case, isn't $\emptyset$ the answer?

Comment: And as @a.r. points out, the answer is $\varnothing$. I think you may have wanted $A_1=\{\varnothing\}$; which is closer to the original badly-LaTeX'd question.

Comment: Oh, if Asaf is right, then it's my fault, sorry: there were a pair of brackets indeed in the original version.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sorry for the bad text, I'm still learning

Comment: While not a duplicate word-for-word, I think this is answered "enough" in the answers to the suggested duplicate.

Comment: This is exactly the question I'm looking for, thanks for this.